# Strange type inference behavior

Tags: purescript

I'm trying to understand why `purescript` is unable to properly infer type for `map` parameter in this simple code:

```
maybeInc :: String -> StateT (Maybe Int) Identity Unit
maybeInc "a" = modify $ map (1 +)
maybeInc _ = return unit
```

Here is my error message:

```
  No type class instance was found for

    Control.Monad.State.Class.MonadState (_0 Int)
                                         (StateT (Maybe Int) Identity)

  The instance head contains unknown type variables. Consider adding a type annotation.
```

However, it works if I specify the type manually:

```
maybeInc "a" = modify $ \(m :: Maybe Int) -> map (1 +) m
```

Why it doesn't want to infer this type automatically even it's already provided in function signature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current compiler has no way of modeling functional dependencies, which are used in Haskell and the `mtl` library to capture the relationship between the two type arguments in `MonadState`.

This means that the compiler can't figure out that the two state types have to be the same (that is, if we find an instance of `MonadState` for `StateT (Maybe Int) Identity`, the state type is forced to be `Maybe Int`).

For now, one solution is to add a type annotation:

```
maybeInc :: String -> StateT (Maybe Int) Identity Unit
maybeInc "a" = modify modifier
  where
    modifier :: Maybe Int -> Maybe Int
    modifier = map (1 +)
maybeInc _ = return unit
```